# Google Text-to-Speech API 400 error for specific paragraph

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I have an integration set up with Google TTS generating audio for a daily Bloomberg email newsletter. It's been working reliably, but I recently received a 400 error for a specific group of sentences:

```
"message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT
```

Sending POST to https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize  with this payload:

```
{
    "input": {
        "text": "Still it hangs together in a rough schematic way, which means you can try it in thecryptomarket. Crypto, particularly decentralized finance, has some key advantages for this, including:\n\n * Weird and fragmented liquidity, so that you can trade with yourself on a futures exchange, and you can move the price of a token a lot on the spot market;\n * A love of mechanical rules and automated markets, so that if your X position spikes from $1 million to $100 million, some decentralized finance platform will say “yup, now it’s worth $100 million, so it’s good collateral for a $40 million loan”; and\n * A presumption of anonymity, so exchanges will let you trade with yourself, and won’t be able to come after you for your losses, since they just have some anonymous wallet addresses."
    },
    "voice": {
        "name": "en-US-Neural2-A",
        "languageCode": "en-US"
    },
    "audioConfig": {
        "pitch": -4,
        "speakingRate": 1.2,
        "audioEncoding": "MP3"
    }
}
```

I've confirmed this behavior is consistent in Google's API explorer, so I think I've isolated the text content itself as the source of the error. I eliminated unescaped characters as a cause by trying a no-symbol version of the text that still failed. API documentation hasn't yielded any clues on allowable characters or other requirements.

The weirdest thing is that the text above works if I delete either the first sentence or the last sentence. Is Google checking the *content* itself for prohibited phrases or something???

Any other ideas to resolve this error?

Comment: Hard to know without more information, but my guess would be that either the string is too long now (character count > max length) or there is a combo of unvalidated characters they are using.  For example, in MYSQL, if you have a backslash in a string and you want to keep it, you need to have 2 sets of backslash so that it doesn't error out there or bypass the rest of the code.  

Try - Cutting the string in half and see if it works ....
If it does then try the other and see if it errors, keep moving around the string cutting it until you isolate the problem area.

Comment: This might be okay but here an example from your string:
g:\n\n *

That is an example of it trying to allow special characters, but perhaps there is an error when it translated it to you, OR your database format is different than the source, so this causes an issue.  And again this might not be the spot, but just giving you hits to look for this sort stuff.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions @easleyfixed . Max character count isn't the culprit - the text is way under the 5000 limit. And I can't see how unescaped characters could be the issue after my testing. These 4 sentences in the input text are actually a subset of a larger message I pared down while chasing the error source. Of these 4 sentences, I get successful results for sentences 1-3 and 2-4...so every part of the input text can succeed. It's just sentences 1-4 combined that fail inexplicably. FWIW, I did try a version with all special characters removed, and it failed too.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back on that.   What about column length?  If each string works on its own, then maybe together they are too many characters to fit? Sort of a textbox vs textblock/blob sort of situation?

Comment: Length won't be the issue either. My integration keeps the text well under Google's 5000 character max, and this problematic segment is just a small subset of a larger payload. In other words, it's much shorter than valid payloads and nowhere near 5000.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much but worth an ask.  I guess what keeps bothering me is the "INVALID_ARGUMENT" part, that makes me think some sort of syntax is missing but I'm just not seeing it, and if its not missing, its added syntax instead, but you said all the special characters are fine, so it is a bit puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neural languages seems to be more strict on the ssml.
You have to include the **speak** tag.
[SSML speak](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-speech-synthesis11-20100907/#S3.1.1)

```
{
    "input": {
        "text": "<speak>Still it hangs together in a rough schematic way, which means you can try it in thecryptomarket. Crypto, particularly decentralized finance, has some key advantages for this, including:\n\n * Weird and fragmented liquidity, so that you can trade with yourself on a futures exchange, and you can move the price of a token a lot on the spot market;\n * A love of mechanical rules and automated markets, so that if your X position spikes from $1 million to $100 million, some decentralized finance platform will say “yup, now it’s worth $100 million, so it’s good collateral for a $40 million loan”; and\n * A presumption of anonymity, so exchanges will let you trade with yourself, and won’t be able to come after you for your losses, since they just have some anonymous wallet addresses.<\speak>"
    },
    "voice": {
        "name": "en-US-Neural2-A",
        "languageCode": "en-US"
    },
    "audioConfig": {
        "pitch": -4,
        "speakingRate": 1.2,
        "audioEncoding": "MP3"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to reproduce this exact same error with multiple AU, UK and US english Neural2 voices using the text you provided. I've also observed this same exact behavior with other random segments of text of my own.

The workaround I've found (and which is working on the text you provided) is to simply use Wavenet voices instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is an ongoing internal bug with the length of text being too long. For the meantime, possible workarounds would be, converting the text into <500 bytes as you mentioned or send the request into smaller pieces.

Hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Found posted three weeks ago here:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Google-TTS-can-t-convert-text-longer-than-500-600-characters/m-p/517771#M1198

I dealt with the same issue, and ended up just coding a function to split larger strings into a list, split by the nearest newline character found, and then iterating over the list as input to the TTS.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified in my answer. I've also set up string splitting in my scripts, and tested with text shorter than 100 bytes, but the 400 error remains when using Neural2 voices, so it's not related to length.